# read Data URL with File API polyfill

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi, polyfills

I am trying to use the File API library (https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI) as a fallback for browsers which do not support the File API, in order to read a file as a Data URL and pass that on to another function.

I have this code:

```
function handleFileSelect(event) {
    // If supported, use native File API.
    if(window.FileReader != null) {
        console.log('Using native File API.'); // !
        var files = event.target.files;
        for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                insertImage(event.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
         }
    }
// Otherwise, use fallback polyfill for browsers not supporting native API.
else {
    console.log('Using polyfill for File API.'); // !
    var file = FileAPI.getFiles(event.target);
    FileAPI.readAsDataURL(file, function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });
  }
}
```

However, console.log(evt) returns an Object which reports error: "filreader_not_support_DataURL".

Have I done something wrong with File API polyfill or is there a shim or other polyfill I have to use to get data URLs to work?

Thanks.

-- Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature is implemented yet via flash - thanks to the author of FileAPI plugin.

```
// bind to your upload container
var el = document.getElementById('uploadElementId');
FileAPI.event.on(el, 'change', function (evt/**Event*/) {
    var files = FileAPI.getFiles(evt);
    // get Data URL for the first file
    FileAPI.readAsDataURL(files[0], function (dataUrlObject) {
        if (dataUrlObject.type == 'load') {
            // Success                    
            var dataUrl = dataUrlObject.result;
        }
    });
});
```

Whole thread here: https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/issues/153

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is clear. You want to use this polyfill to read file as Data URL and it tell you that it dont support Data URL. So I assume there is no other way to do this.

Comment: That's what I assumed in the end too. There is demo code showing data URL usage though; but maybe it hasn't been implemented in the library yet. Thanks.